# Android studio: Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, macos, gradle, android-studio, synchronization

I just have installed Android studio on Mac, updated to version 0.5.4. Then created a new app, just basic thing, by clicking next, next, next...
And After I open "MainActivity", I get an error saying "Gradle project sync failed. Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed: Cause: error in opening zip file"
Any ideas how to solve this? I've been browsing this forum, but no solution found.

Comment: When you create a new project, it has to download a number of libraries from the Internet, and I'm guessing there was a problem with the download. Maybe try creating another new project and see if that works better?

Comment: Thanks, I've created multiple projects, and I got always this error

Comment: You could try deleting the .gradle directory in your home directory and see if that clears anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project where its located

For example:

```
MyApplication->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties
```

go into it and change this row:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

with this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

and try to sync with this button [image]      in your IDE